# How to sort complex numbers by real part follow by imaginary part

Tags: julia

I want to sort a list (or in julia speak an one dimensional array) of complex numbers, by real part then by imaginary part of the complex number. I tried using anonymous function for the lt but it does not work.

```
julia> b=[3 + 1im,1 + 2im,1 + 1im,5 + 6im]
4-element Array{Complex{Int64},1}:
 3 + 1im
 1 + 2im
 1 + 1im
 5 + 6im

julia> sort(b,lt = x,y -> if(real(x)==real(y)) imag(x)<imag(y) else real(x)<real(y) end)
ERROR: UndefVarError: x not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at none:0
```

I want the following results

```
 1 + 1im
 1 + 2im
 3 + 1im
 5 + 6im
```

Answer (score 6):

So close!

```
julia> sort(b, lt = (x,y) -> real(x)==real(y) ? imag(x)<imag(y) : real(x)<real(y))
4-element Array{Complex{Int64},1}:
 1+1im
 1+2im
 3+1im
 5+6im
```

Comment: A bit shorter would be to use `by` like this: `sort(b, by = x -> (real(x), imag(x)))` and use the fact that tuples are sorted using lexicographic order.

Answer (score 0):

Tuples are sorted in lexicographic order (the 1st element; then the second one, and so on).
You could just do:

```
b = [3 + 1im, 1 + 2im, 1 + 1im, 5 + 6im]
sort(b, lt = (x, y) -> (real(x), imag(x)) < (real(y), imag(y)))
```

edit: The comment above, using `by=` , is much cleaner.